# 'NoneType' object is not callable error when using couchbase with git, logbook module

Tags: python, couchbase

I'd experienced weird result when testing couchbase python SDK.
below is the source code and result:

```
# xxx.py
from gcouchbase.bucket import Bucket
dsn = 'couchbase://[url-of-couchbase]/[bucket-name]'
db = Bucket(dsn)

# yyy.py
import logbook
import git
from xxx import db


# python yyy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcouchbase/iops_gevent10.py", line 88, in timer_event_factory
    return GEventTimer()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[1]    8546 abort (core dumped)  python yyy.py
```

The weird thing is, when I remove `import git` or `import logbook` from yyy.py, the error doesn't happen.
Is there any reason for this error? should any resource for couchdb be disposed?

Comment: Well, +1 for type safe compilers. They usually don't allow this sort of thing past them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asynchronous event seems to arrive after the `Bucket` object has been removed.  If you call `bucket._close()` explicitly, the script would not be crashed.  Anyways, it looks like a bug of `gcouchbase`.